# Неверное указание времени вопросов и ответов

Tags: дефект, статус-так-задумано

Что-то с этим неправильно. [Вот](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/457389/%d0%90%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%81) например: написано, будто вопрос я задал вчера и ответил oleedd тоже вчера, между тем это было позавчера. И только когда пройдут полные двое суток, напишут "два дня назад". А если два ответа были в один день **три дня назад**, но у одного не прошло полных трёх суток, а у другого прошло, тогда пишут *"два дня назад"* и *саму дату* соответственно.

*Всё это очень неудобно.*

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд, неоднозначность появляется из-за того как определено понятие «вчера» и от какого времени «вчера» отсчитывается.

[Если я верно понимаю](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/115983/274323), то:

- «сегодня» означает «в рамках 24 часового интервала»;
- «вчера» означает «от 24 часов до 48 часов».

Другими словами, «вчера», «сегодня», «2 дня назад» — это относительные понятия. При этом на времени публикации сообщения есть всплывающая подсказка, которая [отображается в часовой зоне UTC](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/165320/274323).

Comment: "Сегодня" там вообще нету.

Comment: Спасибо! Похоже, так и есть!)